# Realtime sharing of secret notes

Tags: web-apps, security, communication

Looking for a website where a Writer can type secret notes into a "chatbox" using his browser on his laptop, notes which can be read by a Reader in realtime. (The Writer will inform the Reader orally how to access the note, for example by going to a link and typing in a code.)

The reader will be reading using an iPhone browser or an Android phone browser.

Requirements:

1. Reader may also write notes (using his phone) for the writer to read in real-time, but the notes need not be so lengthy.
2. No-registration for Reader.
3. The usual "ability" to notify the Reader when there's something new to read.
4. Session may last for at least 8 hours.
5. Writer may write pretty lengthy notes.

Optional requirements:

1. No-registration for Writer.
2. Real security.
3. Supporting more than one Reader.
4. Reader may use a laptop browser, or even "any browser".
5. Writer may use a phone browser, or even "any browser".

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using one of the readily available messengers? If it's because of the "registration" you might want to elaborate what actually is considered a registration in the scope of your question.

Comment: @Marcel, I do not have anything readily available, what on earth would that be? google.com? No-registration means... no registration? Pastebin / protectedtext.com / paste.rs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the popular messengers. The culprit will be with the "no registration" requirement.

A viable solution in my opinion is [Threema](https://threema.ch) (I am a user).

1. Any of 2 (or more) users can read and write messages
2. You do not need to register with a central service (See below)
3. Notification works with with the phone's built-in notification service (discloses some data with the vendor)
4. "Session" is arbitrarily long
5. You can even send files

It's secure, since you manage your keys on your own. You can have large groups. There is a web client, but you need a phone, since encryption and decryption for the messaging endpoint is done on the phone.

*Registration:* It's a one-time paid service (Crypto and cash payments available). You will be able to manage your private key on your own, no phone number needed. In the end, you can have your identifier shared with anyone and no-one as you like.

Comment: That "web client" seems to require a phone app. Thus Writer cannot really type secret notes into a "chatbox" using his browser on his laptop in and of itself. And Reader cannot read using an iPhone browser or an Android phone browser.